# Mixing power supplies with inductive loads

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, inductive, electromagnet

[image]
I have two unregulated power supply - 24V and 12V.
My board consists of digital components and sensors that require 3.3V or 5V.
All that electronics is resposible for electromagnets or DC brush motors control and PC communication. Electromagnets' rated voltage is 12V and motors' 24V.
My question is how to mix the power supplies?
I consider to power motors separately from 24V. Then I would use 12V to power electromagnets and DC/DC buck converter in parallel. DC/DC buck secondary voltage is 5V. After that there will be linear regulator that converts my 5V to 3.3V. Is it a good solution to use the same power supply for powering electromagnets and dc/dc buck converter that powers electronics resposible for control? Could you delegate me to some books or articles about that?

Comment: Welcome! Can you draw a simple block diagram to aid the understanding what you have?

Comment: Depends if your supply can handle all those inductive loads and still meet the input specifications for the buck converter.